# How to solve "RelativeLayout cannot be cast to a DrawerLayout" error?

Tags: android, layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add a header image or icons in my NavigationDrawer, but all the examples I found/tried aren't useful for my implementation.

Tried to change the drawerlayout to relativeLayout onOptionsItemSelected.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == android.R.id.home){
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navList)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navList);
        }
        else
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(navList);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position, long id) {
    loadSelection(position);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1415)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLayout.java:1677)
    at acr.acr_app.MenuPrincipalActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MenuPrincipalActivity.java:161)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2925)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:403)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:189)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:192)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

**Updated Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout">
<FrameLayout
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragmentholder">
</FrameLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
 android:layout_width="240dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="start"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="200dp"
 android:background="@drawable/acr_home"/>

  <ListView
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:background="@drawable/mb04"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
  </ListView>
  </RelativeLayout>

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Activity_main**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    navList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    navList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    navList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    ArrayList<String> navArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    navArray.add("Home");
    navArray.add("Frag2");
    navArray.add("Frag3");
    navArray.add("Frag4");
    navArray.add("Frag5");

    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,navArray);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>   (this,R.layout.my_text_view,navArray);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);
    actionBarDrawerToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.opendrawer,R.string.closedrawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToogle);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    loadSelection(0);
}
```

Comment: A DrawerLayout is just a view group like any other layout. Just add images the same way you would for any other screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't changed correctly which layout should be closed onClick.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == android.R.id.home){
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerRelativeLayout)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
        }
        else
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e6e6ff"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout">
<FrameLayout
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentholder">
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logodrawerlateral" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/image_view"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your listview inside a layout and above listview place your image view. Please use this reference http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/put-image-navigation-drawer/#sthash.1l6ynBbz.dpbs

Comment: Tried with that example but Im having this error:         "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams"

Comment: Please paste line MenuPrincipalActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MenuPrincipalActivity.java:161) and code block

Comment: Tried to replace the navList with the new relativeLayout in closedrawer, but the error still the same. Thx for the reply.